# Как проверить существование картинки на сервере?

Tags: php

`$artist` - это название картинки

```
<?php

$fileurl = 'https://site.ru/images/artist/'.$artist.'.jpg';

if (is_file('$fileurl')) {
echo "<img src='/images/artist/$artist.jpg";  // Если картинка существует
} else {
echo "<img src='/images/label/thumb/user.jpg'>";  // Если картинка не существует
}
?>
```

Почему постоянно пишет не существует? Пробовал `file_exists` тоже без результатно.
Все файлы находятся на одном сервере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этих функциях должен быть путь на сервере, а не url, так что лучше и название переменной поменяйте

```
$fileurl = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/'. 'images/artist/'.$artist.'.jpg';
```

Вот тут, например, это все расписано - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать file_exist(), потому что если по вашему пути не будет ничего вообще то будут падать оповещания в консоль
Пример кода:

```
if (file_exist('$fileurl')) {
echo "<img src='/images/artist/$artist.jpg";  // Если картинка существует
} else {
echo "<img src='/images/label/thumb/user.jpg'>";  // Если картинка не существует
}
```

А еще лучше тернарный оператор

```
echo file_exist('$fileurl') ? 'вывод в случае если файл есть' : 'вывод если файла нет';
```

Answer (score -2):

Для проверки существования файла есть функция file_exists
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-exists.php